# Cypress - how to get child of a specific parent element

Tags: get, cypress

I am stuck by finding a specific button within my list of items... The button exists 3 times with exact same `data-testid`, but the parent is different. And I end with

> error: `cy.click()` can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 3 elements. Pass `{ multiple: true }` if you want to serially click each element.

HTML:

```html
        <div data-testid="list-item">
          <div>
            <div>
              <span data-testid="status1">
          <button data-testid="details_button">click</button>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div data-testid="list-item">
          <div>
            <div>
              <span data-testid="status2">
          <button data-testid="details_button">click</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

How can I select the details_button of either status1 or status2?

My attempt was:

1. ```js
   cy.get('[data-testid=status1]')
     .get('[data-testid="details_button"]').click()
   ```
2. ```js
   cy.get('[data-testid=status1]')
     .parent().parent()
     .get('[data-testid="details_button"]').click()
   ```

Comment: Are you trying to click on each `data-testid="details_button"` individually or at the same time?

Answer (score 7):

Your first attempt is almost correct, but use `.find()` for the second step

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=status1]')
  .find('[data-testid="details_button"]')  // find works here (same as .within())
  .click()
```

Works for this HTML

```html
<div data-testid="list-item">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span data-testid="status1">
        <button data-testid="details_button">click</button>
      <!-- span closing tag is missing -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason that works is because the HTML posted is slightly invalid - the `<span>` has no closing tag.

Cypress thinks that the button is inside the span, so using `.find()` works.

---

However if that's a typo, you should change to your ***2nd*** command using `.parent()` and also change `.get()` to `.find()`

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=status1]')
  .parent()
  .find('[data-testid="details_button"]')
  .click()
```

Works for this HTML

```html
<div data-testid="list-item">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span data-testid="status1"></span>   
      <!-- span is closed, button is outside span so use .parent() command -->
      <button data-testid="details_button">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfect. And thx for noticinf the errors in the html. I had to cut it down to the major part that i was using.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `siblings()` method is cypress.

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=status1]').siblings('[data-testid="details_button]').click()
cy.get('[data-testid=status2]').siblings('[data-testid="details_button]').click()
```

You can also use a combination of `parent()` and `within()`, something like:

```js
cy.get('span[data-testid=status1]')
  .parent('div')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('button[data-testid="details_button]').click()
  })
cy.get('span[data-testid=status2]')
  .parent('div')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('button[data-testid="details_button]').click()
  })
```

Comment: You don't need a `span` inside your  `.get()` commands in your second example.